# Variable used in localstorage is undefined

Tags: local-storage, token

I'm trying to save a token returned from the server into localStorage. But when I check in Chrome in the developer tools under "Application" for the stored item, it says   [object Object]. But when I console.log this variable, I get the full token which i'm trying to save.

How can I save the token in my localstorage?

Relevant Part:

```
GetToken(body){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        body != null ? resolve(new Object(body)) : reject('Error');
    })
}


fetch(//-POST FUNCTION-//).then(response =>{
        if (response.ok){
            this.GetToken(response).then(value => value.json())
                .then( data => {
                    var servertoken = data; //token gets saved
                    localStorage.setItem('customtoken',servertoken); //variable is [object Object]
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log("wrong")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage only stores string values. Hence, you should stringify your token object.

`localStorage.setItem('customtoken', JSON.stringify(servertoken));`

And to retrieve it, just parse the string

`const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customtoken'));`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> The keys and the values **are always strings** (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

You'll need to serialize the objects into a string, and then deserialize them when you want them back out:

```
GetToken(body){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        body != null ? resolve(new Object(body)) : reject('Error');
    })
}


fetch(//-POST FUNCTION-//).then(response =>{
        if (response.ok){
            this.GetToken(response).then(value => value.json())
                .then( data => {
                    var servertoken = data; //token gets saved
                    localStorage.setItem('customtoken', JSON.stringify(servertoken)); //variable is [object Object]
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log("wrong")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
localStorage.setItem('customtoken',servertoken);
```

try this instead:

```
localStorage.setItem('customtoken',data.servertoken);
```